# How to start batch using start command when CMD is disabled?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make a batch file which will work on computers with CMD disabled. Below is my code. (The bit saying `command` is other code which I have not included.)

If I try running this code, a CMD window will open but it will not run because CMD is disabled. It is opening as a CMD file not a batch file. How can I change this? Or could I make the batch file create a .reg file to enable CMD before the start command is used?

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%f in (%0) do set basename=%%~nf
    set UsPr=%UserProfile%
    copy %0 "%UsPr%"
        if "%0" == "%UsPr%\%basename%.bat" (
            goto :1
        ) else (
            goto :2
        )
:1
    command
    pause
:2
    command
    start "%UsPr%\%basename%.bat"
    pause
```

Comment: The CMD.EXE program executes both batch files and CMD scripts. If CMD.EXE is disabled, then batch files and CMD scripts will not run. If you want to run CMD scripts, you need to work with your system administrator to enable the CMD.EXE program.

Comment: CMD can be disabled via gpedit. It lets you open CMD it just comes up with `"The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator"`. But you can still run batch files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "CMD is disabled". But your START command is failing because your target path is enclosed by quotes (probably by necessity), but START will treat the first argument as a title if it is enclosed by quotes. The solution is to add an additional quoted argument for the title - an empty string will do:

```
start "" "%UsPr%\%basename%.bat"
```

Comment: Administrators can [disable CMD via gpedit](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/prevent-access-to-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7/).

Comment: @SomethingDark - But if CMD were disabled, then START would not open a CMD window :) The title issue is the problem. CMD is not disabled, at least in the OP's case.

Comment: As @SomethingDark said CMD is disabled via gpedit. It lets you open CMD it just comes up with `"The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator"`

Comment: @Neb9 - Thanks, good to know. I've since tried gpedit out and see what you mean.